# Why does my model duplicate itself in pose mode

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones, rigify

Both legs are duplicated when I try to move them in pose mode why?
There's no duplication, in edit mode.

[image]

Comment: check your weight painting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with deformations producing duplicates. I figured it was related to the fact that I had added additional bones to the armature post the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > *Set Parent* > *Armature Deform* action and the new bones were interfering with the deformation since the weights had not been assigned (@David's comment was the clue for me).

To solve this issue you need to go to Object Mode, select the Mesh, then select the armature and redo the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > *Set Parent* > *Armature Deform* action. I used the *Automatic Weights* option as before and Bam!

The deformations in pose mode are back to normal.